# Sequential messaging with RabbitMQ

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-boot, amqp, spring-amqp

I have an application with separate modules A, B , C & D. I have the below queue model for the same:

1. Queue AB connects A and B.
2. Queue BC connects B and C.
3. Queue CD connects C and D.

A message on AB should reach B, process things on B then drop a message on BC to process things on C and call D through CD.

I am using spring-boot-starter-amqp:1.0.1.RELEASE for the above.

A, B , C and D run on different JVMs and connect to the same rabbit MQ server.

I am able to send a message from A -> B receive it on B and send B->C. However, the message is never received by C.
If I restart my JVM for C, the message is received.(The message is already in the queue BC waiting to be received.)

The sender and receiver across modules are on the line as below. It seems to be a configuration issue. Can anyone explain?

```
@Component
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
public class ASender {

    String queueName = "ha-ab";

    @Autowired
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    public void send(Object message) throws AmqpException {
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(queueName, message);
   }

}



@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
public class BReceiver {

     String queueName = "ha-ab";

     @Bean
     public SimpleMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer() {
         SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new      SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
         container.setConnectionFactory(rabbitConnectionFactory());
         container.setQueueNames(queueName);
         container.setMessageListener(messageListener());
         return container;
      }

     @Bean
     public ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
            new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageListener messageListener() {
        return new MessageListener() {
            public void onMessage(Message message) {
                try {
                    doSomething();
                    sendMessageToD();

                } catch (DestinationNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (CampaignNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvalidStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: Turn on DEBUG logging and follow the messages in the logs.

Comment: @GaryRussell : I already have the DEBUG logging enabled which shows the BlockingQueueConsumer in place for module B. However the blocking consumer does not show up in the logs for C.

Comment: There must be something wrong with the configuration. You should examine the DEBUG logs to figure out why. If you can't figure it out, post the logs somewhere (they are too big for Stack Overflow) as well as your complete configuration